# Segmentation Fault Strdup

Tags: c

I have this program that reads a string and splits it in three parts. The first part is opcode, the second is data and the third is key.

Example of use:

```
put this is stackoverflow

opcode: put 
data: this is
key: stackoverflow
```

Code Main:

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv){
          char command[MAX_MSG];
          fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);
          char *data;char *key;
          command[strcspn (command, "\n")] = '\0';
          char *aux_command_key = strdup(command);
          char *aux_command_data = strdup(aux_command_key);
          char *opcode = strtok(command, " ");          
          int success = 0;

          if(strcmp(opcode, "put") == 0){
                key = strdup(getKey(aux_command_key, opcode));
                if(key == NULL){
                       printf("Invalid number of arguments.\n");
                       return -1;
                 }

                 else
                       data = getData(aux_command_data, opcode, key);
          }
          printf("opcode: %s\n",opcode);
          printf("data: %s\n",data);
          printf("key: %s\n",key);               
          free(aux_command_key);
          free(aux_command_data);
}
```

My problem is when I run my program whithout key it gives me Segmentation Fault as result instead of :
"Invalid Number of Arguments".
I don't know why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Run it under a debugger. What line is causing the segfault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `getKey` with the instruction `put`, and you say you didn't provide enough number of arguments in the input. Therefore, it appears to me that `getKey` will return `NULL`. You can't call `strdup` with `NULL`.

My advice: first, call `getKey`, and then, if it doesn't return `NULL`, you can duplicate it:

```
  if(strcmp(opcode, "put") == 0){
        key = getKey(aux_command_key, opcode);
        if(key == NULL){
               printf("Invalid number of arguments.\n");
               return -1;
         }
        else {
               key = strdup(key);
               data = getData(aux_command_data, opcode, key);
         }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you run the program without giving a key presumably `getKey(aux_command_key, opcode)` will return `NULL`.

`strdup()` has undefined behavior if the argument isn't a valid string pointer. (In other words, don't pass a null pointer to `strdup()`).

The POSIX standard says the following about library functions in general (the C standard has similar language, but `strdup()` is part of POSIX, not the C standard):

> 2.1.1 Use and Implementation of Functions
>
> Each of the following statements shall apply to all functions unless
>   explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow:
>
> 1. If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value
>      outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address
>      space of the program, or a null pointer), the behavior is undefined.
>
> ...

Assuming that arguments must be valid unless the docs explicitly state that certain invalid values are handled is a good rule of thumb to follow for pretty much any API. See: ["Basic ground rules for programming - function parameters and how they are used"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/20/555511.aspx)